# What is the most efficient way to store long list (1000) of Objects in Realm?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am trying to store 1000 of data in Realm database at a time, but while storing that data my application UI getting stuck for 10 to 15 min. So my question is, Is there any efficient way to store data in Realm database? so that UI not stuck.

**My code for storing object:** a

```
func addData(object: Item)   {          
    try! database.write {             
        database.add(object, update: true)            
        print("Added new object")          
    }     
}
```

Comment: If it's taking 10 minutes to write out 1000 objects, something else is wrong. One of our apps writes out almost 10,000 rows of data and even on the main thread takes it just a few seconds. You should include more code so we can understand what's your doing as the provided code works correctly - even with 10,000 items. Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I agree that something else is wrong. When writing on the background thread, if you put something like 100000 adds/creates in a single transaction, you will feel the device hang for a few seconds, but it will work. If you break that 100000 up and write 1000 records per transaction, things will go much smoother and you won't see the device get sluggish.

Answer (score 2):

**UI Freeze because you're doing it on the MainThread**, 
for the realm just save all the list at once 
(".modified" is from new realm syntax).

```
try! database.write {
     database.add(objects, update: .modified)
}
```

Comment: @Nilesh There's nothing in the code in the question that would freeze the main thread. While I agree that writing massive amounts for data should be done on a background thread, the code in this answer doesn't do that. Take a look at [Using Realm On a Background Thread](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#using-a-realm-across-threads) for a great example of how to write a million records in the background.